# Make Phone Call Button in Android Web Page

Tags: javascript, android, html

I've got this website that is specifically designed for Android phones. It would be awesome if I could make a button that would make a phone call.

Ideally the code would be something like:

Call NOW

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<a href="tel:1-800-555-1212">Call NOW</a>
```

use tel:1-800-555-1212 as the href